# Converting Percentage

Tags: java

I don't know what to do next :

Create a new class "X" in a new package "prog1.printtools". In this class, first implement a class method "alsProzent" that returns a string value and receives a double and an int as formal parameters. In this method, you should now create (and return) a formatted string that represents a percentage representation of the double value, where the int parameter is to specify the number of decimal places. Use a comma as a decimal separator. A call as percent (0.12345,2) should return the string "12.34%". You do not have to round, but simply cut off more decimal places.

```html
package prog1.printtools;
public class PrintTools {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    public String alsProzent(double m, int n) {
        return
        }
//String Prozentzahldarstellung(double m) = String.format();
```

Comment: check [this out](https://www.google.com/search?q=string+format+float+java) and [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=prozentrechnung).

Comment: This is an (almost) zero effort homework dump. It doesn't contain a [mcve], just some code that wont even compile. This is NOT how you write questions here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is what they are looking for, but you could do this:

```
public String alsProzent(double m, int n) {
    NumberFormat pctFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
    pctFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(n);
    pctFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
    return pctFormat.format(m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 public static String alsProzent(double m, int n){
    String format = String.format("%." + n + "f", m);
    return format;
}

public static void main (String args[]){
    System.out.println(alsProzent(10.2394, 2));
}
```

It's pretty straight forward when using String formatting. I just replaced the traditional decimal point value to take the value of user defined int.

Also I noticed that you've created the function inside a function. That isn't the convention and usually will result in errors. You can call a function or create an object inside another function but you can't define a function inside a function.

Comment: it is also pretty forward to not answer zero-effort homework dumps.